# Access an item of Array of class using a member variable in place of index in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, oop

suppose I have a class like

```
class ABC
{
    int ID;
    public string Name;
    public ABC(int i, string str) { ID = i; Name = str; }
}
```

And declare a array of class ABC.
Assume that I have also initialized each element using new keyword.
Now I want access element of class using it's member ID instead of 0 based index. Make ID public if required.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ABC[] a = new ABC[3];
        a[0] = new ABC(100, "First");
        a[1] = new ABC(101, "Second");
        a[2] = new ABC(102, "Third");

        ABC newobj = a[100]; // where 100 is ID of class ABC
    }
}

class ABC
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    public ABC(int i, string str)
    {
         ID = i;
         Name = str;
    }
}
```

Comment: So why don't you put them into a `Dictionary<int, ABC>` instead?

Comment: can u please give me a sample code.? I dont know how to work with dictionaries in .NET

Comment: I cannot, but Google and MSDN can.

Comment: please vote up my question. I need some points to vote up answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading the indexer on a standard array isn't possible in C#. If you have to go the indexer route I'd suggest using Dictionary or a List class that supplies it's own indexer.

```
class ABCCollection : List<ABC>
{
  public ABC this[int id]
  {
    get { return this.Where(abc => abc.ID == id).FirstOrDefault(); }
  }
}
```

Then you call use ABCCollection[100] to access your item.

Comment: I like this approach.. anyone please tell me is there any drawback of this approach over Dictionary..?? any performance issue..??

Comment: please vote up my question. I need some points to vote up answers.

Comment: can't I override Add() function in my way..??

Comment: Don't inherit from List<ABC> in that case but rather from CollectionBase and implement your own Add method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` to get the right object:

```
ABC newobj = a.Where(abc => abc.ID == 100).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which returns `null` if there's no matching ID.

As @Xanatos has suggested, you could also use this neater version:

```
ABC newobj = a.FirstOrDefault(abc => abc.ID == 100);
```

As @Jon has suggested, it might be better to use a `Dictionary<int, ABC>` to store your ABC instances. It provides better performance than always iterating a `Collection` to find a matching ID. But then the key must be unique, you cannot add two `ABC` instances with the same ID:

```
var a = new Dictionary<int, ABC>();
a.Add(100, new ABC(100, "First"));
a.Add(101, new ABC(101, "Second"));
a.Add(102, new ABC(102, "Third"));
```

You would access it in this way:

```
ABC newobj = a[100];
```

Comment: This could work too: ABC newObj = a.Single(abc => abc.ID == 100); However, none of our methods would work now because the fields are private... :D

Comment: works fine.. thanks for prompt response.. but I want to do this in the same way like we can access cookies with cookie name as Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Value. Is this possible any how..??

Comment: Or more compactly `ABC newobj = a.FirstOrDefault(abc => abc.ID == 100);`

Comment: @ShashwatIndia: I've just added the Dictionary approach.

Comment: A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` (non-unique keys) or a  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (unique keys, as others already wrote) would give you access via an indexer (`abc[100]`). You could also implement your own data structure with an indexer (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), but I think one of the existing classes works perfect.

Comment: Now come to real problem... I have a function GetEmployees() in class Dept that returns an array of class Emp. Suppose Emp has a public property 'Name' and a unique int ID. Now how can I access elements of Emp array like B[100].Name. Where 100 is ID. Do I need to return a dictionary instead of Array. I create array using List<Emp> v = new List<Emp>(); and then just return v.ToArray();

Comment: I'm not sure if i unerstand, but you could simply return that dirctionary entry in your `GetEmployees` method: `return Emp.AllEmployees[ID];`(where `ID` is the int parameter in that method).

Comment: please vote up my question. I need some points to vote up answers.

Comment: @ShashwatIndia: You're also getting 2 points for every accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for working with a [**Dictionary (MSDN)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
//instantiate it: key is of type int, value is of type string
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
//add a few items...
dict.Add(100, "First");
dict.Add(101, "Second");

//get item with key '100'
var first = dict[100];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: please vote up my question. I need some points to vote up answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use LINQ query to solve problem:

```
 var newobj = (from data in a
               where data.ID ==100
               select data).Cast<ABC>();
```

Comment: please vote up my question. I need some points to vote up answers.